# Find the CDF of $Y=(\frac{2}{X+1})^2$ given CDF of X

Tags: probability, probability-theory

CDF of $X$ is $$F_X(t)= \begin{cases}
    1-\frac{1}{4(t+1)^2},& \text{if } t\geq -\frac{1}{2}\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

So now since $Y=(\frac{2}{X+1})^2$ $$F_Y(t)=\mathbb{P}(Y\leq t)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{2}{\sqrt{t}}-1\leq X)$$

How can I use CDF to find the last expresion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You want to find CDF of $Y=(\frac{2}{X+1})^2$

$$P(Y\le y)=P\left((\frac{2}{X+1})^2\le y\right)$$
$$P(Y\le y)=P\left(-\sqrt y\le \frac{2}{X+1}\le \sqrt y\right)$$
$$P(Y\le y)=P\left( \frac{2}{X+1}\le \sqrt y\right)-P\left(-\sqrt y\le \frac{2}{X+1}\right)$$
$$P(Y\le y)=P\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt y}-1\le X\right)-P\left(-1-\frac{2}{\sqrt y}\le X\right)$$

Now use $$P(X\ge x)=1-P(X < x)$$

$$P(Y\le y)=P\left(-1-\frac{2}{\sqrt y}\ge X\right)-P\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt y}-1\ge X\right)$$
$$P\left( X\le  \frac{2}{\sqrt y}-1\right)=1-\frac{1}{4(\frac{2}{\sqrt y})^2}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I don't understand the reason of downvote?

Comment: Correct notation for the cdf is $P(Y\le y)$ rather than $F(Y\le y)$.

Comment: Ok I will change that But in here our school they use this notation or I might have misunderstood

Comment: Cdf is a probability, so the other notation makes no sense. However, it is often denoted as $F(y)=P(Y\le y)$.

Comment: Thanks Is the solution fine now should I solve it more or the hint is enough to solve the problem I think it is sufficient

Comment: @DeepeshMeena I got $F_Y=P(Y\leq y)=1-\frac{1}{4(-1-(2/\sqrt(y))+1)^2} -(1-\frac{1}{4(-1-(2/\sqrt(y))+1)^2})=0$ which would mean $F_Y$ is not CDF, because it does not tend to $1$ as $y\to \infty$ so I think I still need your explenation